# MySql Function Call - Data Not Showing

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am developing a website and i have run into an issue. Basically if you view http://nexusdesign.org.uk/irejobs/training-courses.html it says no result, but in the backend it shows clearly that these have been added to the CMS the same as job listings etc have.

Now ive checked the database and any listings in the backend are showing there just not showing on the main website, the coding for this area is below:

```
    <?php
ob_start();
require_once("conn.php");

$pagename = "training";
$submenu = "trainings";

require_once("header.php");

require_once("pager.php");

$__table = "db_trainings";
$__page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$__id = "TrainingID";
$__uploadfolder = "myimages/";

$NUM_COL = 2;

$NUM_ROW = 5;

$perPage = $NUM_COL * $NUM_ROW;

$page=isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']):1;

$MemberID = $_GET['MemberID'];
if($MemberID != "")
    $andmember = " and MemberID = '".$MemberID."'";

$category = "";
$i = 0;
$r1 = mysql_query("select * from db_training_categories") or die(mysql_error());
while($a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
{
    if($_GET['category-'.$a1['CatID']] == "1")
    {
        if($i != 0)
            $andcategory .= " or ";
        $andcategory .= " t.category = ".$a1['CatID'];
        $i++;
    }   
}
if($andcategory != "")
    $andcategory = " and (".$andcategory.")";

$city = $_GET['city'];
if($city == "enter city")
    $city = $_GET['citys'];

if($city != "" and $city != "enter city")
    $andcity = " and t.city = '".$city."'";

$country = $_GET['country'];
if($country != "")
    $andcountry = " and t.country = '".$country."'";

$stxt = $_GET['srchTxt'];
if($stxt == "enter keywords")
    $stxt = $_GET['srchTxts'];

if($stxt != "" and $stxt != "enter keywords")
{
    $srchTxt = " and (t.title like '".$stxt."%' or t.title like '%".$stxt."' or t.title like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.provider like '".$stxt."%' or t.provider like '%".$stxt."' or t.provider like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.city like '".$stxt."%' or t.city like '%".$stxt."' or t.city like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.terms like '".$terms."%' or t.city like '%".$stxt."' or t.terms like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.price like '".$stxt."%' or t.price like '%".$stxt."' or t.price like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.duration like '".$stxt."%' or t.duration  like '%".$stxt."' or t.duration  like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.qualification like '".$stxt."%' or t.qualification like '%".$stxt."' or t.qualification like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.awardingbody like '".$stxt."%' or t.awardingbody like '%".$stxt."' or t.awardingbody like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.description like '".$stxt."%' or t.description  like '%".$stxt."' or t.description  like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " )";
}   

if ($_GET['sortby'] == "newest") {
    $sortby = "newest";
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID desc";
}
elseif ($_GET['sortby'] == "oldest") {
    $sortby = "oldest";
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID asc";
}
else
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID desc";

$textQuery = "select *,t.city,t.country from db_trainings t, db_members m where t.MemberID <> '' and t.MemberID = m.MemberID and m.advertisementexpiry > 0 and t.active = 'yes' ". $andmember . $andcountry . $andcity . $andcategory . $andmember . $srchTxt . $sortbyt;

//for paging
$ress = mysql_query($textQuery);

$total=mysql_num_rows($ress);

$maxpage = floor($total/$perPage);

if($total%$perPage !=0) 
    $maxpage += 1;

if($page == 0)
{
    $start = 0;
    $page = 1;
}
else    
    $start = ($perPage * $page) - $perPage;

$stop = $start + $perPage;

$qry = $textQuery." limit $start, $perPage";

//echo $qry;
$r = mysql_query($qry);
?>
<script language="javascript">
function showRecords(id)
{
    document.frmItems.page.value = id;
    document.frmItems.method = "get";
    document.frmItems.action = "training-courses.html";
    document.frmItems.submit();
}
function validateForm()
{
    document.frm.action = "training-courses.html";
    document.frm.submit();
}

</script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="corner-box-bot">
<?
        if($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Employer')
            include("employer-menu.html");
        elseif($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Seeking')
            include("seeker-menu.html");
        elseif($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Training')
            include("training-menu.html");
?>            
            <div class="content">
                <div style="float:left;width:280px;"><h1>Training & Skills</h1>
                <strong class="blue" style="line-height: 31px; font-size: 14px;">
                    Upgrade 
                your skills and qualifications?<br />
                    Find out what's available near you:
                <br /><br />
                </strong></div>
                <div style="float:right;width:550px;">
              <p><strong>Training providers: </strong>use www.IrishNursingJobs.ie  to effectively promote your courses to students in the UK &amp; internationally  .</p>
              <strong>Reach  out and speak to a global market of clients and students</strong> 
                    <? 
                        if($_SESSION['MemberID'] == "")
                            echo "<a href='login-training.html' class='blue-btn-04' style='font-size:13px;margin-top:20px;'>ADVERTISE YOUR COURSES HERE</a>";
                        else
                            echo "<a href='training-courses-add.html' class='blue-btn-04' style='font-size:13px;margin-top:20px;'>ADVERTISE YOUR COURSES HERE</a>";
                    ?>                      
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <form name="frmItems" id="frmItems">

                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="MemberID" value="<?=$MemberID?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="srchTxts" value="<?=$stxt?>">

                <div class="side_bar">
                    <h1 style="line-height:1;">Advertising</h1>


                </div>

                <div class="col_710 r-content">

<?
                    if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0)
                    {
                        $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                        $arr = explode('&', $query);
                        if(strchr($arr[count($arr)-1],'page')!='')
                            array_pop($arr);
                        $purl = 'training-courses.html?'.implode('&', $arr);

?>

                    <div class="search-box">
                        <div>
                            <label>Training Title (e.g. Nurse)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txt-field" name="srchTxt" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label>Training Location (e.g. Dublin)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txt-field" name="citys" value="<?=$city?>" />
                        </div>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="blue-btn-02" onClick="showRecords(1);">Search</a>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="sort-bar">
                        <span style="float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px; width: 420px;"><strong class="blue"><?=$total?> courses found</strong></span>
                        <span style="float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px;">Sort by</span>
                        <div class="custom-select-2" id="select-box-05">
                            <select name="sortby" id="sortby" class="input" onChange="showRecords(1);">
                                <option value="newest" <? if($_GET['sortby']=='newest') echo "selected"; ?>>Newest</option>
                                <option value="oldest" <? if($_GET['sortby']=='oldest') echo "selected"; ?>>Oldest</option>
                            </select>                                                                                                                                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding: 25px 0 0 25px;">
<?
                        $i=0;
                        while($a = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                        {
                            $r1 = mysql_query("select * from db_members where MemberID = '".$a['MemberID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1);

                            $r2 = mysql_query("select * from db_categories where CatID = '".$a['category']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);

                            $r3 = mysql_query("select * from db_countries where CountryID = '".$a['country']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a3 = mysql_fetch_array($r3);

                            $r4 = mysql_query("select * from db_training_categories where CatID = '".$a['category']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a4 = mysql_fetch_array($r4);

                            echo "
                                <div class='block-result'>
                                    <img alt='' src='".$__uploadfolder.$a['logo']."' width='134' />
                                    <div class='desc'>
                                        <a href='training-courses-view.html?TrainingID=".$a['TrainingID']."'> ".cleaninput($a['title'],"ss|he|tr")."</a>
                                        <span class='blue'>Location:</span> ".cleaninput($a['city'].", ".$a3['Name'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Sector:</span> ".cleaninput($a4['CatName'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Price:</span> ".$currency.cleaninput($a['price'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Duration:</span> ".cleaninput($a['duration'],"ss|he|tr")." hours<br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ";
                            $i++;
                        }
?>
                        </div>
<?  
                        if($maxpage > 1)
                        echo showpage($page,$purl,$total,$maxpage,$perPage);
                    }
                    else
                        echo "
                            <div class='sort-bar' style='margin-top: 0px'>
                                <span style='float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px; width: 420px;'><strong class='blue'>No results found...</strong></span>
                                <div class='clear'></div>
                            </div>
                        ";
?>
                    </div>

                </form>

                <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
         <? include("bottom-featuredcourses.php"); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
<?php
require_once("footer.php");
ob_flush();
?>
```

Can anyone advise whats going wrong?

Comment: You're not checking if your query succeeds. (You're also running the query once, to get all the records, then working out the pagination from that. You're then running the same query, with an added limit - why not just process the record set you've already got?)

Comment: Any clue what the change in coding would be? mysql is not my strong point!!

Comment: to check if your query succeeds, you need to change `$ress = mysql_query($textQuery);` to `$ress = mysql_query($textQuery) or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: The pagination is a little bit more complex, but not too much more. You need to write a loop that will ignore any records at the start of the resultset (because they're on an earlier page) : `while ($i < $start * per_page)) { $i++; mysql_fetch_array($ress); }`; then you just need to loop through a maximum of $page_num records in your content loop, rather than the whole result set.

Comment: Is that enough for you to get an idea about what's needed?

Comment: Hmmmm ive changed the top coding and its still not showing, can you advise further? P.S. Where are you based?? Might have some work for you as clearly you know this stuff well!!

Comment: Okay sent to andrew @

Comment: @halfer - ta, but he was responding to a comment I've since deleted ;)