# MySql No Results Found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage i am working on, the link is:

http://nexusdesign.org.uk/irejobs/training-courses.html

The code for which is below. Now in the backend i have created entries for the training courses as shown but these arent showing, From what i can father these should be pulled from the database db_trainings both into here and the seperate feature box below,

Can anyone advise whats going wrong here ??

```
    <?php
ob_start();
require_once("conn.php");

$pagename = "training";
$submenu = "trainings";

require_once("header.php");

require_once("pager.php");

$__table = "db_trainings";
$__page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$__id = "TrainingID";
$__uploadfolder = "myimages/";

$NUM_COL = 2;

$NUM_ROW = 5;

$perPage = $NUM_COL * $NUM_ROW;

$page=isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']):1;

$MemberID = $_GET['MemberID'];
if($MemberID != "")
    $andmember = " and MemberID = '".$MemberID."'";

$category = "";
$i = 0;
$r1 = mysql_query("select * from db_training_categories") or die(mysql_error());
while($a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
{
    if($_GET['category-'.$a1['CatID']] == "1")
    {
        if($i != 0)
            $andcategory .= " or ";
        $andcategory .= " t.category = ".$a1['CatID'];
        $i++;
    }   
}
if($andcategory != "")
    $andcategory = " and (".$andcategory.")";

$city = $_GET['city'];
if($city == "enter city")
    $city = $_GET['citys'];

if($city != "" and $city != "enter city")
    $andcity = " and t.city = '".$city."'";

$country = $_GET['country'];
if($country != "")
    $andcountry = " and t.country = '".$country."'";

$stxt = $_GET['srchTxt'];
if($stxt == "enter keywords")
    $stxt = $_GET['srchTxts'];

if($stxt != "" and $stxt != "enter keywords")
{
    $srchTxt = " and (t.title like '".$stxt."%' or t.title like '%".$stxt."' or t.title like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.provider like '".$stxt."%' or t.provider like '%".$stxt."' or t.provider like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.city like '".$stxt."%' or t.city like '%".$stxt."' or t.city like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.terms like '".$terms."%' or t.city like '%".$stxt."' or t.terms like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.price like '".$stxt."%' or t.price like '%".$stxt."' or t.price like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.duration like '".$stxt."%' or t.duration  like '%".$stxt."' or t.duration  like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.qualification like '".$stxt."%' or t.qualification like '%".$stxt."' or t.qualification like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.awardingbody like '".$stxt."%' or t.awardingbody like '%".$stxt."' or t.awardingbody like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " or t.description like '".$stxt."%' or t.description  like '%".$stxt."' or t.description  like '%".$stxt."%'";
    $srchTxt .= " )";
}   

if ($_GET['sortby'] == "newest") {
    $sortby = "newest";
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID desc";
}
elseif ($_GET['sortby'] == "oldest") {
    $sortby = "oldest";
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID asc";
}
else
    $sortbyt = " order by t.TrainingID desc";

$textQuery = "select *,t.city,t.country from db_trainings t, db_members m where t.MemberID <> '' and t.MemberID = m.MemberID and m.advertisementexpiry > 0 and t.active = 'yes' ". $andmember . $andcountry . $andcity . $andcategory . $andmember . $srchTxt . $sortbyt;

//for paging
$ress = mysql_query($textQuery);

$total=mysql_num_rows($ress);

$maxpage = floor($total/$perPage);

if($total%$perPage !=0) 
    $maxpage += 1;

if($page == 0)
{
    $start = 0;
    $page = 1;
}
else    
    $start = ($perPage * $page) - $perPage;

$stop = $start + $perPage;

$qry = $textQuery." limit $start, $perPage";

//echo $qry;
$r = mysql_query($qry);
?>
<script language="javascript">
function showRecords(id)
{
    document.frmItems.page.value = id;
    document.frmItems.method = "get";
    document.frmItems.action = "training-courses.html";
    document.frmItems.submit();
}
function validateForm()
{
    document.frm.action = "training-courses.html";
    document.frm.submit();
}

</script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="corner-box-bot">
<?
        if($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Employer')
            include("employer-menu.html");
        elseif($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Seeking')
            include("seeker-menu.html");
        elseif($_SESSION['MemberType'] == 'Training')
            include("training-menu.html");
?>            
            <div class="content">
                <div style="float:left;width:280px;"><h1>Training & Skills</h1>
                <strong class="blue" style="line-height: 31px; font-size: 14px;">
                    Upgrade 
                your skills and qualifications?<br />
                    Find out what's available near you:
                <br /><br />
                </strong></div>
                <div style="float:right;width:550px;">
              <p><strong>Training providers: </strong>use www.PaediatricNursingJobs.com  to effectively promote your courses to students in the UK &amp; internationally  .</p>
              <strong>Reach  out and speak to a global market of clients and students</strong> 
                    <? 
                        if($_SESSION['MemberID'] == "")
                            echo "<a href='login-training.html' class='blue-btn-04' style='font-size:13px;margin-top:20px;'>ADVERTISE YOUR COURSES HERE</a>";
                        else
                            echo "<a href='training-courses-add.html' class='blue-btn-04' style='font-size:13px;margin-top:20px;'>ADVERTISE YOUR COURSES HERE</a>";
                    ?>                      
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <form name="frmItems" id="frmItems">

                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="MemberID" value="<?=$MemberID?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="srchTxts" value="<?=$stxt?>">

                <div class="side_bar">
                    <h1 style="line-height:1;">Advanced Search</h1>
                    <h2 class="blue">Course Location</h2>

                    <div class="custom-select-2" id="select-box-01">
                        <select name="country">
                            <option value="">select country</option>
<?
                            $r2 = mysql_query("select * from db_countries order by Name = 'United Kingdom' desc, Name") or die(mysql_error());
                            while($a2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2))
                            {
                                if($a2['CountryID'] == $country)
                                    echo "<option value='".$a2['CountryID']."' selected>".$a2['Name']."</option>";
                                else
                                    echo "<option value='".$a2['CountryID']."'>".$a2['Name']."</option>";
                            }   
?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="custom-select-2" id="select-box-02">
                        <input type='text' name='city' class='txt-field-2' value='enter city' />
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4; padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <h2 class="blue">Course Subject</h2>
                        <div class="custom-select-2" id="select-box-04">
<?
                            $r1 = mysql_query("select * from db_training_categories order by CatName") or die(mysql_error());
                            while($a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
                            {
                                if($_GET['category-'.$a1['CatID']] == "1")
                                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category-".$a1['CatID']."' value='1' checked /> ".$a1['CatName']."<br />";
                                else
                                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category-".$a1['CatID']."' value='1' /> ".$a1['CatName']."<br />";
                            }
?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4; padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="blue-btn-06" onClick="showRecords(1);">Search for course</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col_710 r-content">

<?
                    if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0)
                    {
                        $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                        $arr = explode('&', $query);
                        if(strchr($arr[count($arr)-1],'page')!='')
                            array_pop($arr);
                        $purl = 'training-courses.html?'.implode('&', $arr);

?>

                    <div class="search-box">
                        <div>
                            <label>Training Title (e.g. Nurse)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txt-field" name="srchTxt" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label>Training Location (e.g. Bristol)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txt-field" name="citys" value="<?=$city?>" />
                        </div>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="blue-btn-02" onClick="showRecords(1);">Search</a>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="sort-bar">
                        <span style="float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px; width: 420px;"><strong class="blue"><?=$total?> courses found</strong></span>
                        <span style="float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px;">Sort by</span>
                        <div class="custom-select-2" id="select-box-05">
                            <select name="sortby" id="sortby" class="input" onChange="showRecords(1);">
                                <option value="newest" <? if($_GET['sortby']=='newest') echo "selected"; ?>>Newest</option>
                                <option value="oldest" <? if($_GET['sortby']=='oldest') echo "selected"; ?>>Oldest</option>
                            </select>                                                                                                                                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding: 25px 0 0 25px;">
<?
                        $i=0;
                        while($a = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                        {
                            $r1 = mysql_query("select * from db_members where MemberID = '".$a['MemberID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1);

                            $r2 = mysql_query("select * from db_categories where CatID = '".$a['category']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);

                            $r3 = mysql_query("select * from db_countries where CountryID = '".$a['country']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a3 = mysql_fetch_array($r3);

                            $r4 = mysql_query("select * from db_training_categories where CatID = '".$a['category']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $a4 = mysql_fetch_array($r4);

                            echo "
                                <div class='block-result'>
                                    <img alt='' src='".$__uploadfolder.$a['logo']."' width='134' />
                                    <div class='desc'>
                                        <a href='training-courses-view.html?TrainingID=".$a['TrainingID']."'> ".cleaninput($a['title'],"ss|he|tr")."</a>
                                        <span class='blue'>Location:</span> ".cleaninput($a['city'].", ".$a3['Name'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Sector:</span> ".cleaninput($a4['CatName'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Price:</span> ".$currency.cleaninput($a['price'],"ss|he|tr")."<br/>
                                        <span class='blue'>Duration:</span> ".cleaninput($a['duration'],"ss|he|tr")." hours<br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ";
                            $i++;
                        }
?>
                        </div>
<?  
                        if($maxpage > 1)
                        echo showpage($page,$purl,$total,$maxpage,$perPage);
                    }
                    else
                        echo "
                            <div class='sort-bar' style='margin-top: 0px'>
                                <span style='float: left; display: block; padding-top: 4px; width: 420px;'><strong class='blue'>No results found...</strong></span>
                                <div class='clear'></div>
                            </div>
                        ";
?>
                    </div>

                </form>

                <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
         <? include("bottom-featuredcourses.php"); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
<?php
require_once("footer.php");
ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through. I suggest paring it down to the trouble spot if you know where it is. Also, please don't use mysql_* functions in new code http://bit.ly/phpmsql. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation. Learn about Prepared statements http://j.mp/T9hLWi instead, and use PDO http://php.net/pdo or MySQLi http://php.net/mysqli. This article: http://j.mp/QEx8IB can help you decide which.

Comment: To be honest im absolutely clueless where this is concerned - thats the problem. Basically the page http://nexusdesign.org.uk/irejobs/training-courses.html is showing no results but the entry db_trainings in mysql is filling nicely

Comment: That's a lot of queries...

Comment: I know, i didnt write the code im afraid, just trying to get it to display correctly.

Comment: And which query is empty when it shouldn't be? You should post only that query to avoid people skipping the question due to the amount of code.

Comment: Find the query that is being run, and run it directly against your database. I suspect you're debugging this on the server too; download a copy to your local machine, and get it working there - it's much easier to debug.

Comment: that line that says "echo $qry" would be perfect to uncomment and run in your database im sure it returns 0 results

Comment: I think its here: $textQuery = "select *,t.city,t.country from db_trainings t, db_members m where t.MemberID <> '' and t.MemberID = m.MemberID and m.advertisementexpiry > 0 and t.active = 'yes' ". $andmember . $andcountry . $andcity . $andcategory . $andmember . $srchTxt . $sortbyt;

Comment: im sure it is, but that is a massive query with no possibility of figuring out what the variables are. Are there any columns in the db_members table with m.advertisementexpiry > 0??

Comment: All of the members tables show advertisementexpiry at 0

Comment: Also i tried to uncomment echo $qry and it still shows zero

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql Function Call - Data Not Showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115146/mysql-function-call-data-not-showing)

Comment: it is possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above:

> ```
>   all of the members tables show advertisementexpiry at 0
> ```

Your query tries to match anything with advertisementexpiry > 0. That means the query will never match any rows since none are greater than 0.

Comment: Can anyone be specific - at the moment we have http://nexusdesign.org.uk/irejobs/training-courses.html where some results are showing, i reset the mysql databse but any new additions in the backend arent showing and the item titles are meant to be clicking through to the course detail - this section is broken and needs repair if anyone can provide clear guidance how to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

you need to break down this bit `t.MemberID <> '' and t.MemberID = m.MemberID and m.advertisementexpiry > 0 and t.active = 'yes'`

test each piece to debug

```
t.MemberID <> ''
```

looks like its not needed as i am pursuming every member has a id.